# Which data is in an Android minidump?

Tags: android, crashlytics, privacy

I currently need to document which data is collected for an Android app for GDPR. That app uses Crashlytics. The only [official information](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy) I can find is:

> Retention: Firebase Crashlytics keeps crash stack traces, extracted minidump data, and associated identifiers (including Crashlytics Installation UUIDs and Firebase installation IDs) for 90 days before starting the process of removing it from live and backup systems.

I'm pretty sure this can contain any data processed by the app. However, is it limited to the app? Could there be data in the minidump which is not part of the app / which the app does not have access to?

Also important: Could this leak private keys?